# Comparing data within files

Tags: python, python-3.x, diff

The below code is comparing 2 files and outputting the difference if there is any into a 3rd file.
 If there is NO differences in both of the files, it will then output the word 'ALL GOOD' into the 3rd file.
The issue that I am having is when there is a difference in both files, it is still include the words 'ALL GOOD' along with the differences whereas I only want to output the differences in the 3rd file and only output 'ALL GOOD' when there is NO difference.

```
with open('master.txt','r') as masterfile:
    with open('file','r') as usedfile:
        difference = set(masterfile).difference(usedfile)

with open('text3.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    if difference:
        for line in difference:
            file_out.write(line)
    else:
        file_out.write('ALL GOOD')
```

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the code which you are running. I don't believe it will write differences *and* "ALL GOOD", unless "ALL GOOD" is one of the differences.

Comment: Hi Zvone, i have tested the code, it write 'All GOOD' still when there is a difference. it outputs the difference in the 3rd txt file as well the words 'ALL GOOD'. not sure why that's why i posted this question.

Comment: Did you try running in a debugger to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are using `set().difference(t)` instead of `set().symmetric_difference(t)`

From the python docs, `set().difference(t)` is defined as returning a `new set with elements in s but not in t`, whereas `set().symmetric_difference(t)` returns a `new set with elements in either s or t but not both`.

Take this code for example:

```
>>> s1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> s2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> set(s1).difference(s2)
set()
>>> set(s1).symmetric_difference(s2)
{6}
```

As you can see, `set().difference(t)` does not return the difference between two sets, but rather any elements in s1 that are not in s2. I believe if you replace the line

```
difference = set(masterfile).difference(usedfile)
```

with

```
difference = set(masterfile).symmetric_difference(usedfile)
```

then your code will work.

Comment: thank you for taking a look, however it is still including the words 'ALL GOOD' when there is a difference in the files, when it shouldn't

Comment: This does not answer the question which was asked. It comments on a different topic. Comments section should be used for that.